# Youtube caption converter force closes application in Android

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, caption

I have integrated youtube in an kitkat android application. On clicking the caption converter option the application force closes the application. Gives exception as:

```
02-09 15:07:44.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8691): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0a0108
```

02-09 15:07:44.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8691):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:274)
02-09 15:07:44.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8691):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:277)
02-09 15:07:44.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8691):     at eqv.a(SourceFile:39)
02-09 15:07:44.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8691):     at adu.f(SourceFile:580)
02-09 15:07:44.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8691):     at aid.run(SourceFile:251)
02-09 15:07:44.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8691):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-09 15:07:44.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8691):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-09 15:07:44.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8691):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-09 15:07:44.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8691):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
02-09 15:07:44.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8691):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-09 15:07:44.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8691):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-09 15:07:44.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8691):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
02-09 15:07:44.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8691):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)

Please help.. If it is not possible to solve how can the caption be disabled?

Comment: Please try to find 0x7f0a0108 in gen/your/package/name/R.java

Comment: There is no resource as such...also no toast is referring to it

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is that you have resources for different human languages, and the string is missing for one of the languages.

Another possible cause is that you use a library, the library code tries to find some resource IDs, but the library code has no access to the original library resources and tries to find the ID in your resources... I have seen such a problem a while ago, at that moment I could not find a reasonable solution. Try this:
[Replace (or "Override") String in Android Library Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263259/replace-or-override-string-in-android-library-project)

PS
In the log I see:

```
02-09 15:07:44.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8691):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:277)
02-09 15:07:44.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8691):     at eqv.a(SourceFile:39)
02-09 15:07:44.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8691):     at adu.f(SourceFile:580)
02-09 15:07:44.602: E/AndroidRuntime(8691):     at aid.run(SourceFile:251)
```

What are the mentioned functions from SourceFile?

Comment: The app is running fine in jelly bean and no resource as such has been referred in the code. The app is not multilingual

Comment: just integrated the youtube using youtubeAPI jar and assigning YPlayer widget

Comment: for each library there should be an example project, did you try it first?