# Overriding string resources from module/library that have translations in Android

Tags: android, string, maven, resources

I'm using a library (maven package) that contains translated strings while my app only has resources in English. According to the following, does this mean that I won't be able to Override the string resources of this library? Is there some way I can exclude the translated strings from the maven package?

> This is exact, but it will fail if the string is translated in the library. The translated version in lib override the using-app version (translated or not).

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263259/replace-or-override-string-in-android-library-project)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the library has a values-en folder. Although you have overridden values/strings.xml, the actual text uses the string in values-en/strings.xml if the language selected is English.

Try to override it in the files below:

```
values/strings.xml
values-en/strings.xml
values-(any other language)/strings.xml
```

Answer (score -2):

yes you can use apktool to extract the translations, change them and pack them back.[apktool link](https://code.google.com/hosting/moved?project=android-apktool)